# Root and IAM User not allowed to pass EKS Role when creating EKS cluster from console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-eks

I'm having a problem where I can't create a cluster from console, logged in as root user.
This is the error message for root :
`You are not allowed to pass the role arn:aws:iam::095370286149:role/EKS_Cluster_Role`

[image]

and this is the similar error logged in as IAM User :

[image]

I already created the EKS Role :

[image: EKS Cluster Role]

Also attached in creation form :

[image: attached role in form]

Is there any step that I missed in the creation process?

Thank you for your attention and help

Comment: The issue might be using the root user. It's advised to create an IAM user and use that instead of the root user. EKS specifically ties authentication to the cluster to the user who created it, and that could be the issue with creating with root.

Comment: Okay I will try using IAM @jordanm

Comment: I already tried to use IAM user but have the same error. I think it is related to the EKS role

Comment: Does the Role's Trust Policy permit it to be assumed by EKS?

Comment: I'm having the same exact problem. I was able to successfully create a cluster with this exact role just a few days ago. Now, I can't. I've tried modifying the role and stuff - but nothing works. It looks like an AWS bug to me. I've tried creating a cluster through the UI and through Terraform - same exact error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already solved this problem.

My solution is creating an IAM User, give it full privilege policy (AdministratorAccess), then create EKS cluster using that user.

This time it works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me actually too. It's surprising and unfortunate that the root user can't do this.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my testing, we need an IAM user, and I found that in addition to the standard permissions required for creating an EKS cluster (such as managing EC2 instances, VPCs, etc.), the IAM user also needs the sts:AssumeRole permission. This permission is critical for allowing the IAM user to pass the EKS cluster role to the EKS service during cluster creation.

Here is a suitable IAM policy to attach to the IAM user or group:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

This policy grants the ability to assume any role. However, for better security and adherence to the principle of least privilege, it's recommended to specify the exact ARN of the EKS cluster role in the Resource field, instead of using "*".

Note: Granting AdministratorAccess can resolve the issue as suggested by @Skygazer but is not recommended due to its broad permissions. The above solution is a more secure approach.